# apimcli list apis : 400 Bad request

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have wso2am-2.5.0 and apimcli-1.1.0

all downloaded from here: https://wso2.com/api-management/install/

i try to configure and use `apimcli` with wso2am running locally

so, i've added the environment named `local`:

```
apimcli add-env -n local 
    --apim          https://localhost:9443  
    --registration  https://localhost:9443/identity/connect/register 
    --import-export https://localhost:9443/api-import-export-2.2.0-v2
    --api_list      https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis 
    --token         https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

note the parameter `--api_list` defined in documentation as `--list`

but `apimcli add-env --help` displays `--api_list` instead

and finally I try to get list of apis:

```
apimcli list apis -e local -u admin -p admin --insecure --verbose
```

but it gives me the following output:

```
Executed ImportExportCLI (apimcli) on Wed, 26 Sep 2018 15:59:48 EEST
[INFO]: Insecure: true
[INFO]: apis called
[INFO]: Environment: 'local'
[INFO]: Reg Endpoint read: https://localhost:9443/identity/connect/register
Getting ClientID, ClientSecret: Status - 403 Forbidden
Error: <nil>
Body: 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error 403</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>
    </body>
</html>
Error: Request didn't respond 200 OK: 403 Forbidden
[INFO]: EnvKeysAll: &{map[]}
[ERROR]: connecting to https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
apimcli: Unable to connect. Reason: Status: 400 Bad Request
[ERROR]: Unable to connect.: Status: 400 Bad Request
Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the publisher API version is wrong.

`--api_list      https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis`

Make it `v0.13` and try again.

---

**Edit:** It seems the DCR endpoint is also wrong. Change it like this.

`--registration  https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.13/register`

It seems the readme file shipped with the cli is not correct. :-/

Please use the following doc instead.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Migrating+the+APIs+and+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: the problem in question is solved. thanks. but i got the new one during export: `apimcli export-api -n first -v 1.0.0 -r admin -e local -u admin -p admin --insecure` -> `[ERROR]: Error exporting API: first: Get https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp: Auto redirect is disabled`

Comment: The import/export war is also wrong. You need to use the correct version.

Comment: @daggett I currently have the same issue than you : Auto redirect is disabled. Did you find a solution at this issue?

Comment: @jdel, carefully follow the instructions for your APIM server version and then it should work